# Render text Output in Flexdashboard Sidebar

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

I have a data frame that contains the following columns. *Partner* & *Contact Person*.

```
Partner <- c("Google", "Microsoft", "Apple","Amazon")
ContactPerson <- c("Andrew","Mary","John","Barbara")
DF <- data.frame(Partner, ContactPerson)

# Create a variable called Partner Organisation
PartnerOrg <- DF$Partner
```

In flexdashboard, I'd like a dynamic functionality, such that  when a person selects **Google** under the as a selectInput function, a render outbox output of **Andrew** appears below the dropdown menu. Below is the code in my `rmd` file in the sidebar of my flexdashboard

```
selectInput(
  "Select", label = h5("Select partner organisation"), 
  choices= PartnerOrg,
  
   hr(),
  fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value")))
)
```

```
function(input, output) {

  # You can access the value of the widget with input$select, e.g.
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$select })

}
```

When I run the rmd file to load the dashboard, I get an error
**"Error: argument is not interpretable as logical"**

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you wrapped the UI code to add the `verbatimTextOutput("value")` inside `selectInput`, i.e. `hr()` is passed to the `selected` argument and `fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value")))` to the `multiple` argument. I can only guess that you get the error as the latter requires a `logical`. When I use your code I get an error

> Error in if (multiple) selectTag$attribs$multiple <- "multiple" :
> the condition has length > 1

instead, but for the same reason.

To fix your issue move the UI code outside of `selectInput` as I do in the minimal reprex below:

````
---
title: "FOO"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
Partner <- c("Google", "Microsoft", "Apple","Amazon")
ContactPerson <- c("Andrew","Mary","John","Barbara")
DF <- data.frame(Partner, ContactPerson)

# Create a variable called Partner Organisation
PartnerOrg <- DF$Partner
```

Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
selectInput(
  "Select", label = h5("Select partner organisation"), 
  choices = PartnerOrg
)
verbatimTextOutput("value")
```

```{r}
output$value <- renderText({ 
  subset(DF, Partner %in% input$Select, "ContactPerson", drop = TRUE)
})
```
````

[image]

**UPDATE** To set text color and the font weight of the text output you could add the below chunk of `CSS` code to your rmd. For more on styling or theming a `flexdashboard` document see https://rstudio.github.io/flexdashboard/articles/theme.html#add-css-styles-1.

````
```{css}
.shiny-text-output {
  color: #da70d6;
  font-weight: bold
}
```
````

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I can format the text of the output, to be bold and of a different color?

Comment: I just added an update to show the quick and dirty way to achieve that.