# 'Object' not found on Flexdashboard After running on the browser

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I had an issue that was solved using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73783770/render-text-output-in-flexdashboard-sidebar/73785558?noredirect=1#comment130291659_73785558). But I will replicate the whole code for full follow-through.

The below code works well. It's supposed to render output on the sidebar based on a select input. The data frame is hypothetical and it's created inside the R markdown file.

````
---
title: "FOO"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
Partner <- c("Google", "Microsoft", "Apple","Amazon")
ContactPerson <- c("Andrew","Mary","John","Barbara")
DF <- data.frame(Partner, ContactPerson)

# Create a variable called Partner Organisation
PartnerOrg <- DF$Partner
```

Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
selectInput(
  "Select", label = h5("Select partner organisation"), 
  choices = PartnerOrg
)
verbatimTextOutput("value")
```

```{r}
output$value <- renderText({ 
  subset(DF, Partner %in% input$Select, "ContactPerson", drop = TRUE)
})
```
````

I reproduced this solution by loading an external R-script which contains the data frame

````
---
title: "FOO"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}

# sys.source("Scripts/DataMunge.R", envir = knitr::knit_global())
source("Scripts/DataMunge.R", local = knitr::knit_global())
```

Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
selectInput(
  "Select", label = h5("Select partner organisation"), 
  choices = PartnerOrg
)
verbatimTextOutput("value")
```

```{r}
output$value <- renderText({ 
  subset(DF, Partner %in% input$Select, "ContactPerson", drop = TRUE)
})
```
````

The R Script

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(wesanderson)
library(rsconnect)

Partner <- c("Google", "Microsoft", "Apple","Amazon")
ContactPerson <- c("Andrew","Mary","John","Barbara")
DF <- data.frame(Partner, ContactPerson)

# Create a variable called Partner Organisation
PartnerOrg <- DF$Partner
```

The code works fine in the emulator, but on the browser, I get an error saying **'Object' not found**

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

For me it works when you remove the argument `local = knitr::knit_global()`, so that the sourced data is available in the Rmarkdown/shiny session.

```
source("Scripts/DataMunge.R")
```

Comment: It works. I have known the issue. When I add CSS to the YAML header and refer it to a CSS file, the filter doesn't show. Might you know any particular reason?